# How to replace the last two '/' characters from a string in Go

Tags: go

```
profilePicture := strings.Replace(tempProfile, "/", "%2F", -2)
```

I tried this code but its replace all `/` in the string

```
tempProfile = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/passporte-b9070.appspot.com/o/profilePicturesOfAbmin/original/1492674641download (3).jpg?alt=media"
```

the result which want is

```
tempProfile = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/passporte-b9070.appspot.com/o/profilePicturesOfAbmin%2Foriginal%2F1492674641download (3).jpg?alt=media"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, from the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace):

> Replace returns a copy of the string s with the first n non-overlapping instances of old replaced by new. If old is empty, it matches at the beginning of the string and after each UTF-8 sequence, yielding up to k+1 replacements for a k-rune string. **If n < 0, there is no limit on the number of replacements.** *(Emphasis added)*

Which explains why your -2 isn't working.

The simplest approach to your stated problem is probably something like this:

```
parts := strings.Split(tempProfile, "/")
parts = append(parts[:len(parts)-3], strings.Join(parts[len(parts)-3:], "%2F"))
profilePicture := strings.Join(parts, "/")
```

But a better approach is probably to do proper URL encoding with the [`url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package.